# cant acess magento connect manager magento 1.9 ,

Tags: magento-1.9

i tried to install fooman extension   ( disabled compilation mode etc)

now when i try to go to magento connect manager at my site 
it shows error

update : cant access site   says  "There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons"

[image: screenshot]

tried solution given [here](http://tutorialmagento.com/how-to-solve-exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons) but it didn't worked

Comment: Are you able to turn on exception printing to see what the error is. Under `System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings` Changed enabled to yes

Comment: i cant acess my admin panel

Comment: Don't use connect, instead install it on your own, you can find common extension here: https://github.com/fooman/common

Comment: but i am unable to use my site backed 

first issue is to get the site live

Comment: are you able to login to the server and look at the report number in your screenshot?

Comment: i can use my cpanel at host

Comment: yess , an this is what it shows in error log  as in screenshot